# POSTGRESQL: How to query nested JSONB object to get a filtered JSONB object?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Input Json

```
{
"orderId": "order1",
"fulfillerId":"ful1",
"orderDetailsUrl":"het",
"items":[{
        "decorationTechnology":"laserEngraving",
        "itemId":"item1",
        "productName":"Test Sku for Oracle testing"
    },
    {
        "decorationTechnology":"laserEngraving",
        "itemId":"item2",
        "productName":"Test Sku for Oracle testing"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output JSON

```
{
   "fulfillerIds":[
      "ful1"
   ],
   "orderIds":[
      "order1"
   ],
   "itemIds":[
       "item1",
        "item2"
   ]
}
```

Need to form above expected JSON tried to use row_to_json() and jsonb_array_elements() but couldn't get the expected output

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: version 11.8  @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Postgres 12 or later, you can use SQL/JSON path queries:

```
select jsonb_build_object(
         'orderIds', jsonb_path_query_array(the_column, '$.orderId'), 
         'fulfillerIds', jsonb_path_query_array(the_column, '$.fulfillerId'),
         'itemIds', jsonb_path_query_array(the_column, '$.items[*].itemId')
       ) as filtered
from the_table;
```

Comment: Since I am using version 11.8 this might not work for me @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

With earlier versions it works with concatenation and building arrays:

```
WITH t1 AS
    (
        SELECT '{ "orderId": "order1", "fulfillerId":"ful1", "orderDetailsUrl":"het", "items":[{ "decorationTechnology":"laserEngraving", "itemId":"item1", "productName":"Test Sku for Oracle testing" }, { "decorationTechnology":"laserEngraving", "itemId":"item2", "productName":"Test Sku for Oracle testing" } ] } '::jsonb AS field
    )
SELECT jsonb_build_object('orderId', json_build_array (field->>'orderId')) || jsonb_build_object('fulfillerId', json_build_array (field->>'fulfillerId')) || jsonb_build_object('orderDetailsUrl', json_build_array (field->>'orderDetailsUrl')) AS jsonb_result
FROM t1
;
```